# (Feature Request) Microsoft Translator for Linux, chrome, Firefox and macOS

Tags: translation, microsoft-translator, bing-translator-api

Microsoft Translator
I think it is really beneficial for users if there is an app available for Microsoft Translator in Linux, macOS, Firefox addon and Chrome addon on chrome store. is it possible?

Comment: Why not ask the maintainers of that software?

Comment: I heard that this forum is the new forum from (https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=translator) that focused on Microsoft Translator development. So, I hope MS can understand user feedback.